# Woocommerce - Instead of going to Cart go to another Product? (Only one Category)

Tags: redirect, woocommerce, cart

I'm building a site where you get a free item (you can choose what color) with your purchase of another item category. Is there a way to make the 1 category type, when you click on add to cart, gets redirected to the one free product? All other categories however would not be redirected.

Comment: Why not just add the free item to the cart with a notification that this is what has happened? Oh, colour choice...

Comment: As you can see my issue. The owner of the site is rather picky, however does not want to use anything but Woocommerce :\

Answer (score 1):

You can add a redirect depending on what product ID was added to the cart (Through the "added-to-cart" GET variable). And then getting the category ID from that.

```
// Add redirect action
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_cart_product', 0 );

function check_cart_product(){

    // get product ID, then category ID
    $product_ID = $_GET['added-to-cart'];
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($product_ID,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids'));
    $cat_id = (int)$term_list[0];

    // check if product is from specific category, then redirect
    if($cat_id == 25) 
      wp_redirect(get_permalink(352));

}
```